# what does "javax.websocket.Session.getbasicremote.sendtext" not throwing an IOException mean?

Tags: java, exception, websocket

When websocket sendtext()

```
javax.websocket.Session.getbasicremote.sendtext(...)
```

does not throw an IOException, which of the following happend? 
     A) server sent the message without a problem 
     B) server sent the message and client received the message without a problem

Thanks.